# RPG Maker MV + UWP + No Sound

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, web-audio-api, visual-studio-cordova, rpgmakermv

I am trying to build a RPG Maker MV project using VS 2017 + Cordova for UWP purposes. Responders should ideally know how RPG Maker MV works.

I've got it working perfectly...except for the fact that none of the sound works. It's mostly .OGG sound. I am trying it with Windows x86, Local Machine. The sound works just fine in the MV environment and the sound on my system in general works fine too.

When a sound file plays, I get: 'WEBAUDIO17014: Decoding error: The stream provided is corrupt or unsupported' errors.

Is there a way around this, and how can I get this working? I'm so close!

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear:  WebAudio can't decode your ogg files.  I think you need to verify that it is supported or encode your audio with something else that is supported.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. How would I encode the files differently or get around this so it will work?

Comment: I assume maybe mp3 is supported. Try that. Or figure out why you can't decode the ogg files?  It's really hard to come up with solutions when there are no examples of what you're doing or the files that can't be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this (for Windows 10 at least) by replacing the default sound system with Howler.js with a few UWP tweaks. On XBox One it still doesn't seem to work, but for Windows 10, this works just fine.